# Composite Interval Partitioning - First by month and subpartition by date - Oracle 11g R2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

We have to pull snapshot data from the source(SQL Server) to target(Oracle). The data in the source is mostly appended everyday although there could be few deletes and updates. Since the data is updated and deleted in the source, it would be hard to know what data we had on a particular date in the past unless we pull everyday snapshot data into the target by having a new field "as_of_dt". Considering the reporting requirements on top of the target table, it is better to partition by month and subpartition by date.

I can create the table as below -

```
CREATE TABLE SUBPART_TABLE
(
  AS_OF_DT DATE,
  AS_OF_DAY NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(DAY FROM AS_OF_DT)) VIRTUAL,
  ... more COLUMNS
)
partition by range (AS_OF_DT) interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))
   SUBPARTITION BY LIST (AS_OF_DAY)
   SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
     (SUBPARTITION P01 VALUES (1),
      SUBPARTITION P02 VALUES (2),
      SUBPARTITION P03 VALUES (3),
      ...
      SUBPARTITION P30 VALUES (30)
      SUBPARTITION P31 VALUES (31)
      )
(  
  partition P201706 values less than (to_date('2017-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
);
```

Looking at the explain plan, I figured that I would have to include the below two filters for Oracle to do only a **single subpartition scan** -

```
WHERE AS_OF_DT = TO_DATE('2017-06-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND AS_OF_DAY = 15;
```

How can I partition by month and subpartition by date using the same date field (in this case - "as_of_dt") so that I don't have to include an additional filter for Oracle to scan only the subpartition belonging to that date ?

If you're wondering why I'm not partitioning on just date rather than partitioning on month and then subpartioning on date, the reason is there would be too many main partitions (365/year) which I don't think is good idea.

Comment: Why subpartitioning is better than just more partitions?

Comment: In general a subpartition is the same as a partition. In my opinion the name "subpartition" is a bit misleading. [Composite Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-BE424ACC-F746-4CA8-973C-F578CF98FF10.htm#VLDBG00225) is the better term. The hierarchical dependencies between partition and subpartition are just relevant for creation, the segments are the same for partition and subpartition, i.e. it does not make any difference if your query has to access a partition or a subpartition.

Comment: Oracle allows 1024K - 1 partitions, i.e. more than a million. 365 should be no problem, ohterwise what about 1 week, i..e `partition by range (AS_OF_DT) interval (numtodsinterval(7,'DAY'))`